# How to get progress value precision?

Tags: javascript, html

the value only reach half of max (159). How to get value range 0 to 335?

```js
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');

progress.addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(e.offsetX);
});
```

```html
<progress id="progress" value="50" max="335"></progress>
```

Comment: Make your progress 335 in width, `e.offsetX` returns a x position of mouse inside of progress. It has nothing to do with the max="335" you set

Comment: @Huangism So what property to access that element?

Comment: Looks like it's already working the way it's supposed to.  When I set the `value` attribute to 50, it takes up about 1/6th of the progress bar, exactly as I would expect it to.  Click the "Run Code Snippet" button.

Comment: @davidstephen I believe `.value` on the progress element returns the value

Comment: @Huangism still 159 max. what do you change?

Comment: @davidstephen what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @davidstephen: 159 appears to be the `width` of your progress bar.  Are you sure you're reading the correct attribute?

Comment: @davidstephen: `offsetx` reads where the mouse click is.  It's based on the width of the progress bar, not the max of value.

Comment: Pretty sure he wants to figure out how much from 0 to the `max` was clicked. Eg a click a fourth of the way across a bar with a `max` 1000 should be 250

Comment: @Huangism video duration progress bar.

Comment: Read CertainPerformance's answer below.

Comment: @davidstephen then you do a calculation based on the width of the bar and where you clicked, see the upvoted answer

Answer (score 2):

The `offsetX` is giving you not a fraction of how far in `progress` the mouse was clicked, but the number of pixels from the left edge of the element the mouse was clicked.

For example, with your current code, a `max` of `4567` would also log values between 1 and 160ish - *because the width of the `<progress>` element is 160 pixels*.

Instead, identify the width of the element in pixels, then calculate the fraction of the total yourself and multiply it by the max value:

```js
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');

progress.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const { width } = progress.getBoundingClientRect();
  const frac = e.offsetX / width;
  console.log(frac * progress.max);
});
```

```html
<progress id="progress" value="160" max="335"></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a click listener that calculates the percentage of the mouse offset by the width of the component.

If you try to set a value that is less than the minimum allowable, set it to the min if defined.

```js
const handleProgressClick = ({ target, offsetX }) => {
  const
    { offsetLeft, clientWidth } = target,
    percent = (offsetX - 1) / (clientWidth - 2),
    min = parseInt(target.getAttribute('min') || '0', 10),
    max = parseInt(target.getAttribute('max') || '100', 10);
  let value = Math.round(percent * max);
  if (value < min) value = min;
  if (value > max) value = max;
  const actualPercent = ((value / max) * 100).toFixed(2);
  target.value = value;
  target.closest('.progress-wrapper')
    .querySelector('.display').textContent = `${value}/${max} (${actualPercent}%)`;
};

document.querySelectorAll('progress').forEach(progress => {
  // Add listener
  progress.addEventListener('click', handleProgressClick);
  // Call listener directly
  handleProgressClick({ target: progress, offsetX: progress.value })
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

.progress-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progress-wrapper progress { cursor: pointer; }

.progress-wrapper .display {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress value="0" max="335"></progress>
  <div class="display"><!-- 0/355 (0.00%) --></div>
</div>
<div class="progress-wrapper">
  <progress value="0" min="25" max="75"></progress>
  <div class="display"><!-- 25/75 (33.33%) --></div>
</div>
```